# Java Web App NOT using annotation

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, controller, web.xml

Need to build an application NOT using annotations that are used in >Java3 and having a bit of trouble starting off. Seems like the setup in web.xml/view/controller is logical and should work. Gives a 404 error, if i use annotations it does not. I guess this is why the assignment states not to use annotations! any advice from the old timers on S.O?

P.S any advice would really help me to start this application, i'm reading around online and the solutions i have read don't seem to work. And most end up suggesting to use annotations... which i can not use!

*welcome.jsp*

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Welcome Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome Page</h1>

<br/>

<form action="/OptionsForYou" name="options">

<select>
    <option>---Select---</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

*OptionsWork.java*

```
package com.server;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class OptionsWork
 */

public class OptionsWork extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String options = req.getParameter("options");
        System.out.println(options);
    }

}
```

*web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Options</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>OptionsWork</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.server.OptionsWork</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>OptionsWork</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/OptionsForYou</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Cross-check your dependencies..

Comment: try specifying load-on-startup and Sysout something in implementation to make sure servlet is being loaded or not. Also just a thought, you should specify request method in <form> so that the right method is executed on servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, that unless your webapp is deployed in the ROOT context, you have to specify the context path in any link, including the form's `action` attribute.

Let's say your app is deployed as `myApp` (i.e. in Tomcat in `$TOMCAT_ROOT/webapps/myApp` folder), then your `welcome.jsp` has URL `http://localhost:8080/myApp/welcome.jsp` and the `OptionsWork` servlet "sits" at `http://localhost:8080/myApp/OptionsForYou` URL. But if you specify only `/OptionsForYou` in `<form action="/OptionsForYou" name="options">`, then you call `http://localhost:8080/OptionsForYou`, which, indeed, does not exist, and you get 404 error.

So, add `<%= request.getContextPath() %>` **before** the `/OptionsForYou` to include the context path in the action, i.e. your `<form>` tag should look like

```
<form action="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/OptionsForYou" name="options">
```

and it should work.